# prove there exists some $C > 0$ so that $\lambda > 1\Rightarrow \int_0^\infty e^{-\lambda (x^3 + x^5)}dx = C\lambda^{-1/3} + O(\lambda^{-1})$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, sequences-and-series, definite-integrals

> Prove there exists some $C > 0$ so that $\lambda > 1\Rightarrow \int_0^\infty e^{-\lambda (x^3 + x^5)}dx = C\lambda^{-1/3} + O(\lambda^{-1})$.

> This is problem 9 from [this problem set](https://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/%7Ex46wang/Weekly/2022/A4.pdf).

The hint from the problem set says to consider $\int_0^\infty e^{-\lambda x^3} - e^{-\lambda (x^3 + x^5)}dx$. It could be that the two integrals are close in value. Neither integral seems like it can be directly evaluated using methods like substitution, integration by parts, etc. I know that $e^x = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \dfrac{x^k}{k!}$ for all real numbers x, but even if I substitute this into the given integral, I'm not sure if I can interchange the relevant sum and the integral. The exponent of $x^k$ in $(x^3+x^5)^m$ is $\sum_{0\leq i_1, i_2, 3i_1 + 5i_2 = k, i_1+i_2 = m} \dfrac{m!}{i_1! i_2!},$ though I'm not sure if this is useful. In particular, we have $\int_0^\infty e^{-\lambda x^3} dx = \int_0^\infty \sum_{k=0}^\infty \dfrac{(-\lambda x^3)^k}{k!}dx,$ and clearly we cannot interchange the sum and integral in this case. I'm not sure if Abel's theorem could be useful: if $\sum_k a_k$ converges, then $f(z)=\sum_k a_k z^k$ is continuous from the left at 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, consider the change of variable $y = \sqrt{\lambda x^3}$.
Then,
$$ \int_0^{\infty} \exp(-\lambda x^3) dx = \frac{2}{3} \lambda^{-1/3} \int_0^{\infty} y^{-1/3} \exp(-y^2) dy = C \lambda^{-1/3}.$$

Second, by using the inequality that $0 \le 1 - \exp(-\lambda x^5) \le \lambda x^5$,
$$ \int_0^{\infty} \exp(-\lambda x^3) - \exp(-\lambda (x^3 + x^5)) dx \le \int_0^{\infty} \lambda x^5 \exp(-\lambda x^3) dx.$$

By using the change of variable $y = \sqrt{\lambda x^3}$ again,
$$ \int_0^{\infty} \lambda x^5 \exp(-\lambda x^3) dx = \frac{2}{3} \lambda^{-1} \int_0^{\infty} y^3 \exp(-y^2) dy = O(\lambda^{-1}).$$

Comment: Use an indefinite integral $\int y^{-1/3} dy = \frac{3}{2} y^{2/3} + C$. $\int_0^1 y^{-1/3} dy$ is an improper integral in the sense of the Riemann integral, so we should consider $\int_0^1 y^{-1/3} dy = \lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \int_{\epsilon}^{1} y^{-1/3} dy$, but it is easy to see that this converges.